# Why django-admin.py executed in root not virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am working in ubuntu. I have installed the django==1.3 in root earlier. Now I created local virtual environment name as **local_env** using `virtualenv`. Then I activated the **local_env** using **source** command.But I didn't install the django in this **local_env** environment. When I try to create the django sample project using

```
django-admin.py startproject sampleproject
```

it is working perfectly. My question is,It didn't prevent the **local_env** from the **root** environment ?. I mean it didn't raise the error like `django-admin.py command didn't found`. Please put the comments if any doubts.

Comment: Have you created virtualenv using `--no-site-packages` option? BTW, in latest `virtualenv` it is the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`django-admin.py` is in the OS path. When you try executing it inside your virtual environment, the python will look into it's VE's `sys.path` and if not found it will search through the OS path, found it from the root environment and so there were no errors shown.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/faq/troubleshooting/#command-not-found-django-admin-py), the django-admin.py command is installed on your system path, so if the virtualenv doesn't find this command, it will probably look in the global sys path and find a match.

If you want to use a different version of django to the one installed on your sys path, you will need to install it in your vritualenv using a package manager like pip and this will then take precedent over the global django-admin.py

To make sure you're doing this right, load your the virtualenv using

```
dhanna@dhanna:~$ source local_env/bin/actviate
```

If successful, your prompt should have the virtualenv name at the beginning - eg

```
(local_env)dhanna@dhanna:~$
```

Note that if you activate the virtualenv in one shell, but run the python interpreter inside a separate shell, you will be using the global interpreter and therefore have the global django-admin.py module available.

Next you'll want to install the django module

```
(local_env)dhanna@dhanna:~$ pip install django
```

To check if django is installed inside your virtual env, you can use the package management tool pip and pass the freeze argument

```
(local_env)dhanna@dhanna:~$ pip freeze
```

Now you can use the virtualenv's version of django-admin.py

```
(local_env)dhanna@dhanna:~$ django-admin.py startproject sampleproject
```